# Why do all of my scripts say No MonoBehavior scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity project, I had a bunch of C# scripts that were working pretty well. Then, I created one new one, without editing it, and tried to attach it to an object. All of the sudden, every single C# script wouldn't connect to any game object, and above every script it said, "No MonoBehavior scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name."

I am so frustrated, and have gone to many different threads, looking for how to fix this, but none of their solutions worked for me. What is happening?

Comment: The obvious solution would be to make sure that all the scripts inherit from `MonoBehavior` and that the class name matches the file name. But I guess you already know this. So it's hard to know what could be the exact problem without any screenshots or images.

Comment: I just put spaces in my script names. My bad